# What's the best way to get from São Paulo–Guarulhos International Airport to the city?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, brazil, sao-paulo, gru

Edit 3: Define "best" however you see fit. Personally, I prioritize safety/reliability and cost over comfort and time.

If you Google the above question, there are a good amount of results: buses, taxis, private car services, etc. I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on these (heading into the Vila Mariana neighborhood to be specific), but in particular, has anyone had success using Uber to get a car from the airport?

Edit: some more relevant information is that I speak no Portuguese but some Spanish, am traveling alone, will arrive at 6:45 AM local time, and will have no baggage apart from a small backpack (not a hiking backpack).

Edit 2: More details per comment suggestions are that I value safety and price over speed but am willing to compromise on one for the betterment of another. In particular, a private car booked from a reputable site is about 100USD. Treating this as a benchmark, I am wondering if I can get an Uber or taxi or cheaper which is at least as safe.

Comment: what do you mean by best? Fastest/ Cheapest? Or are you just wondering if it's possible to user uber?

Comment: @MarkMayo Personally, I don't care how long it takes as long as it's safe and reasonably priced. And yes, I am also wondering if it's possible to take Uber, and if so, how expensive and reliable it is especially at off peak times.

Comment: Add these details to your question then.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my definition best based on those qualities may (is not) the same as any elses.... this is still an off-topic question

Answer (score 2):

A taxi from Guarulhos is not very reasonably priced, in my opinion. I'm not sure about *from* Guarulhos, but *to* Guarulhos from Vila Mariana can be 50 USD, depending on the time of day.

There are private shuttle buses that cost about 30 reais (10 USD or so) that take you to either the Tiete or Barra Funda bus terminal. There are a few sales offices for these directly after leaving the terminal. If you're lucky, they have wifi on board.

From Tiete and Barra Funda you can get the metro into Vila Mariana.

There are also public buses that move between the airport and, I think, metro stop Tatuape. This costs 5 or 6 reais, if my memory serves me correct. From there, you can get into Vila Mariana.

Speaking a little bit of Spanish will allow you to ask around for where a public bus will get you to a metro station.

I have no experience with Uber in São Paulo. Their competitors (there are several ([1](http://easytaxi.com.br), [2](http://www.99taxis.com)) mobile apps that allow you to get a cab) are widely used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What are the name of the "competitors" you mentioned at the end? Lyft?

Comment: It. Is. Done. Enjoy.